# How to dynamically set multiple choices to a picklist of a Flow Screen using a resource of type 'Choice'

Tags: picklist, data-types, screen-flow, collection-variable

Is there any way of dynamically setting multiple choices to a picklist of a Flow Screen using a resource of type `Choice`? It seems a collection variable of type `Choice` cannot be created nor can it be used as the `Choice` variable of a Flow UI picklist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't assemble a collection of Choice resources. However, you may be able to solve your use case with the [Quick Choice component](https://unofficialsf.com/quick-choice-improved-picklists-and-radio-buttons-for-flow/), which accepts collection variables of type String, allowing you to assemble choices with a variety of techniques.